# Best way of caching sorted data in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, caching

Assume we have an application which present continuous data to user. E.g. blog - we present list of blog entries and this list is divided into pages - so we end up with /page1, /page2 etc.

The first page is obviously requested most often, but the higher number of page the less often it is requested.

If we implement cache for our app we have two choices:

- update cache of every page after every new entry
- when a page is requested PHP is looking for cached version; if it exists it is returned, otherwise the cache is created with expiration date set to, let's say, an hour

First solution seems like a really waste of resources to me. The second one creates possibility of dangerous scenario:

What happends if user requests for pages x and then (x+1), where page x is cached and page (x+1) is not? If cache for page x is outdated then on page (x+1) user'll see the same content. Or worse, what if user go from x page to (x-1) page? He'll miss some entries!

How to implement caching to avoid this problem?

Comment: Best "key" is to use the query and create a hash of the SQL, then you can keep convention. Or the URL in your case

Answer (score 0):

It's usually best to cache on demand, not cache eagerly unless you can be assured that the work done there won't be wasted.

Typically you use a backing store like Memcached do hold your transient data. This can be configured with a "time-to-live" (TTL) That will automatically expire anything that becomes stale or hasn't been used.

Generally you cache a good chunk of the page into a string, then save that using an identifying key of some sort. In your case the page URL or some subset of the parameters might serve as sufficiently unique. Remember that if the user session has an impact on the contents of this section, then something relating to that, such as `user_id` must be part of the cache key as well.